# Cognos filter linked to checkbox

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

Is it possible to link between filter and promptcheck box

I want when check box is yes to procced with

[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[NEXTSTAGE] in ?NEXTSTAGE?

else

[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[NEXTSTAGE] include 'Arrival announced'

is that possible? i did read if and case statment aren't well in filters and was wondering if we can add it on check box parameter

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your checkbox feeds into a Parameter called 'pArrivalChoice'.  You set it to return 'Yes' when they pick yes, and 'No' when they pick 'No'.

```
( ?pArrivalChoice? = 'Yes' AND 
  [BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[NEXTSTAGE] in ?NEXTSTAGE? )
   or ( ?pArrivalChoice? = 'No' AND 
         [BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[NEXTSTAGE] include 'Arrival announced' )
```

If you want a single check box for yes, and unchecked returns No, then you are going to have to do some scripting of the controls on the prompt page using an HTML item.